# Get the id of a WooCommerce product category by its name or slug

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, custom-taxonomy

I have a wp template that I would like to assign to some pages. The template would ie. display all WooCommerce products that have the same master category name as the pages name itself.

By far I have tried using this code, but with no good output:

```
$idObj = get_category_by_slug($pagename);
$id = $idObj->term_id;
echo ": ". $id;
```

Unfortunately, the echo does not display anything.
Echoing `$pagename` works, and returns me the slug of the page.

Any good way I could make this work?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

With a custom taxonomy is recommended to use `get_term_by()` instead :

```
$category = get_term_by( 'slug', $pagename, 'product_cat' );
$cat_id = $category->term_id
```

Reference: [Get category ID from term slug…](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95502/get-category-id-from-category-slug-not-working)

---

To get a product category ID from term name, use:

```
$category = get_term_by( 'name', $pagename, 'product_cat' );
$cat_id = $category->term_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be correct, try a var_dump to see what you are getting from get_category_by_slug($pagename)

```
$idObj = get_category_by_slug($pagename);
var_dump($idObj);
```

Comment: Just for reference: This is for Wordpress "categories". WooCommerce categories use "product_cat" so you have to use get_term_by()